# css :hover effect no longer works when javascript onscroll event is triggered

Tags: javascript, html, css

in javascript I have onscroll event that moves the div elements depending on window.pageYOffset. In the css I have a :hover that applies transform: scale();

When the page loads, the css effect works. However, as soon as you start scrolling and the onscroll event is applied, the divs that moves no longer respond to the hover effect. The divs that don't have scroll event still have the css effect. Any idea what is causing the conflict?https://jsfiddle.net/kshatriiya/b2jxg3ep/1/

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box" id="one"></div>
  <div class="box" id="two"></div>
  <div class="box" id="three"></div>
  <div class="box" id="four"></div>
  <div class="box" id="five"></div> 
</div>

<div id="scroll-container">
  <div class="box move" data-offset="12" id="six"></div>
  <div class="box move" data-offset="14" id="seven"></div>
  <div class="box move" data-offset="16" id="eight"></div>
  <div class="box move" data-offset="18" id="nine"></div>
  <div class="box move" data-offset="20" id="ten"></div>  
</div>
```

JS

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var movingBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
var boxArray = [];

(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 254) + 1);
boxes[i].style.background = "rgba(" + r + "," + i*30 + "," + i*45 + ", 1)";
}
})();

var boxItem = function(el, speed) {
this.el = el;
this.speed = speed;
this.startOffset = this.speed*10;
};

boxItem.prototype.update = function(Yoff) {

var spd = (Yoff)/(this.speed/(this.startOffset/10));
var distanceRemain = this.startOffset-spd;
if (distanceRemain < 0) {distanceRemain = 0};
this.el.style.transform = "translateY(" + distanceRemain + "px)";

}

function prepareArrays() { 
for (i = 0; i < movingBoxes.length; i++) {
boxArray.push(new boxItem(movingBoxes[i], movingBoxes[i].getAttribute("data-offset")));
};
}

prepareArrays();


window.onscroll = function() {
var Yoffset = this.pageYOffset;

boxArray.forEach(function(el){

el.update(Yoffset);

});
}
```

css

```
#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-diretion: row;  
}

.box {  
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100px;
 -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-out, transform 3s ease;
 -moz-transition: width 1s ease-out, transform 3s ease;
 -ms-transition: width 1s ease-out, transform 3s ease;
 -o-transition: width 1s ease-out, transform 3s ease;
 transition: width 1s ease-out, transform 3s ease;
 background: red;
}

.box:hover {
transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

#scroll-container {

 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-content: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the transform you have applied via  javascript is overriding the transform on hover because styles applied via js are inline styles

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty obvious, you're overriding the same CSS reference on the same element.

Try putting `!important`, from the CSS `.box:hover` transform, that will do the trick